# Sagepay Direct - PHP integration with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, opayo

I have set up a simple Wordpress site with an order form but I'm struggling to get the site to recognise Sage Pay.

I've been following the initial instructions in the PHP integration kit - http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/direct-integration-documents:

1. Create a database and add the necessary tables.
2. Edit the /lib/config.php and the /demo/config.php to include my Sagepay Account and database details
3. In the test server for Sage Pay I also added the IP address of my site as an exception.

Every time I run the https://mywebsite.com/demo it returns the error:

> Ooops!!!
>
> > An unexpected error seems to have occurred.
> >     Try to refresh the page or you can contact us if the problem persist.

This is pretty early on in the but I seem to be doing something wrong. Is there something else that needs edited as the instructions are frustratingly vague.

Would I be better just using a Sagepay Direct plug in with Wordpress e-commerce solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a currently frustrated Sagepay learner.  To asnswer you question, I had this problem too.  My problem was that i had the database details incorrect.  I had my local host details on my test environment, and i had not changed the details correctly in demo/config.php before ftp the file to my webserver.  Once i did this, i got over the oops screen.  The next problem was that i got a blank screen when running index.php from demo.  I was told by sagepay that apache needs restarting as a service everytime somethingortheother happens.  So on my local environment i restarted all services in wamp and it worked.  I can now see the demo (not that i know what to do now as there are no instructions and the php is hidden in a complex class structure with the html content in some tpl files which i have never seen before - of course there are no instructions in the integration kit at all).  Anyway back to the answer.  So locally i can run the demo, but i still have white screen on my webserver, becuase i can't restart the apache service there, so that is the next problem.  I will keep trying and add anything useful later.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, I had not given the database user account the necessary permissions to access the database.